# Как воспроизвести вертикальное видео на C#?

Tags: c#, .net, видео

Здравствуйте. Есть необходимость воспроизводить видео на форме в вертикальной ориентации, т.е. повернуть видео на 90 градусов. Какие библиотеки можно использовать?

Пробовал Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback, но не нашел там возможности поворота.

Возможно в libvlc.dll это есть, но её не получилось запустить.
Как можно воспроизводить видео на форме с поворотом на 90 градусов?
Спасибо.

Comment: Для VLC нужно использовать SDK, а не только одну библиотеку libvlc.dll. Оболочки VLC SDK для .NET до сих пор нет. Если только самому её писать или портировать на .NET то, что есть. Также для Вашей задачи можно посмотреть в сторону ffmpeg.

Comment: К слову, о VLC в интернете есть, как минимум, одна реализация для работы под .NET, но в списке на официальном сайте VLC SDK её нет. Т.е. её можно смело считать неофициальной со всеми вытекающими последствиями.